# In Oracle what is the fastest way to limit the characters in a string?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, full-text-search, oracle11gr2

I have quite a number of text fields I need to deal with. In order to process them the first thing I need to do is to normalize the set of characters I deal with. I need my output string to contain the following;

A-Z, 0-9 and space and I want all lower case converted to upper case.

So I use the following in pl/sql;

```
X := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE
(REGEXP_REPLACE(X, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
```

This is rather slow. What would be faster?

Comment: how do you know this is the slow part of your processing?  what else is being done?  I guess more context on your process as a whole would be helpful

Comment: Yes `regexp` functions on Oracle are VERY slow.

Comment: I know it is slow because I have run "dbms_hprof.start_profiling('PROFILER_DIR', 'test.trc');" and analyzed the results. I run this for nine fields per row, which can have anywhere from null to no more than 10,000 characters. There are other things I am looking at, but this is one thing that is complained about. I will try to isolate these lines in their own procedure, to really isolate their performance.

Comment: interesting question actually, so to test I ran 1 million rows (of 9 varchar feilds) through a test using this regex code vs a simple UPPER.  I processed the conversions using upper in 5 seconds vs 50 seconds for the regex.  A big difference, but 50 seconds really isn't a big deal in batch processing.  If performance is really a problem with your process, it may be from your overall approach (hence my earlier question).  For example, processing the conversion iteratively in a cursor loop may be slower than doing it in a single SQL statement.  But still a good question on its own, so +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks for your  input. The process, takes 9 text fields per row and "annotates" certain words and phrases, and additionally determines whether the word or phrase should be negated. Once it has annotated the text it then attempts to make decisions based on the annotations to classify the record overall, and then it extracts bits & pieces to extract usable data points. Overall ~1,500 lines of code, the data gathered annually is ~800,000 rows. I have to process about 11,000,000 historical rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach, which looks to be much faster based on some (very) loose tests.  Its a function that's compiled natively:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function clean_string(
    in_string    in varchar2)
 return varchar2 AS
   out_string varchar2(4000) := '';
   in_length number;
   cnt number := 0;
   in_char char(1);
   out_char char(1);
   dec_char number;
   prev_space boolean := false;
begin
   --dbms_output.put_line('In string: ' || in_string);
   in_length := LENGTH(in_string);
   while cnt < in_length
   LOOP
     cnt := cnt + 1;
     in_char := substr(in_string, cnt, 1);
     dec_char := ascii(in_char);
     -- blank out non alphanumerics
     IF (
       (dec_char >= 48 AND dec_char <= 57) OR
       (dec_char >= 65 AND dec_char <= 90) OR
       (dec_char >= 97 AND dec_char <= 122)
       ) THEN
         --keep it
         out_char := in_char;
     ELSE
       out_char := ' ';
     END IF;

     IF (NOT(prev_space AND out_char = ' ')) THEN
       out_string := out_string || out_char;
     END IF;

     <<endloop>>
     IF (out_char = ' ') THEN
       prev_space := true;
     ELSE
       prev_space := false;
     END IF;

   END LOOP;
   return trim(upper(out_string));
end;

ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_CODE_TYPE=NATIVE;
ALTER function clean_string COMPILE;
```

And to test, I pulled 5 million rows from a table and cleaned some strings:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    cursor sel_cur1 is
    select name, clean_string(name) as cln_name,
        address1, clean_string(address1) as cln_addr1,
        address2, clean_string(address2) as cln_addr2,
        city, clean_string(city) as cln_city,
        state, clean_string(state) as cln_state,
        postalcode, clean_string(postalcode) as cln_zip
    from my_table
    where rownum <= 5000000;

    cursor sel_cur2 is
    select name,
        address1,
        address2,
        city,
        state,
        postalcode
    from my_table
    where rownum <= 5000000;

    l_cnt integer := 0;
    l_cln_name varchar2(100);
    l_cln_addr1 varchar2(100);
    l_cln_addr2 varchar2(100);
    l_cln_city varchar2(100);
    l_cln_state varchar2(100);
    l_cln_zip varchar2(100);

    l_interval interval day to second(4);
    l_start timestamp;
    l_end timestamp;
begin
   l_start := systimestamp;
   for rec in sel_cur2
   loop
         l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
         l_cln_name := clean_string(rec.name);
         l_cln_addr1 := clean_string(rec.address1);
         l_cln_addr2 := clean_string(rec.address2);
         l_cln_city := clean_string(rec.city);
         l_cln_state := clean_string(rec.state);
         l_cln_zip := clean_string(rec.postalcode);
   end loop;
    l_end := systimestamp;
    l_interval := l_end - l_start;
    dbms_output.put_line('Procedural approach timing: ' || l_interval);
   -------------------------------------------------
   l_cnt := 0;
   l_start := systimestamp;
   for rec in sel_cur1
   loop
         -- cleaning already done in SQL
         l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
   end loop;
   l_end := systimestamp;
   l_interval := l_end - l_start;
   dbms_output.put_line('SQL approach timing: ' || l_interval);

   -------------------------------------------------
   l_cnt := 0;
   l_start := systimestamp;
   for rec in sel_cur2
   loop
         l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
         l_cln_name := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(rec.name, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
         l_cln_addr1 := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(rec.address1, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
         l_cln_addr2 := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(rec.address2, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
         l_cln_city := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(rec.city, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
         l_cln_state := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(rec.state, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
         l_cln_zip := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(rec.postalcode, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
   end loop;
   l_end := systimestamp;
   l_interval := l_end - l_start;
   dbms_output.put_line('Existing approach timing: ' || l_interval);
end;
```

And the output was:

```
Procedural approach timing: +00 00:02:04.0320
SQL approach timing: +00 00:02:49.4326
Existing approach timing: +00 00:05:50.1607
```

Also, the native compilation seems to only help a procedural approach to the processing (rather than calling the function from a SQL query), but appears to be much faster than the regexp_replace solution.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that I am not really answering my own question, but I am accepting tbone's answer. The reason for providing this answer, is the comments don't let me post what I really want.

I created a function almost identical to tbone's with a couple of tweaks, got rid of the UPPER by changing how I handle the lower case range of characters, and changed numbers to binary_integers.

```
  FUNCTION CLEAN_STRING(IN_STRING in VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 
  AS
    OUT_STRING VARCHAR2(32767) := '';
    IN_LENGTH BINARY_INTEGER;
    CNT BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    IN_CHAR CHAR(1);
    OUT_CHAR CHAR(1);
    DEC_CHAR BINARY_INTEGER;
    PREV_SPACE BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  BEGIN
    IN_LENGTH := LENGTH(IN_STRING);
    WHILE CNT < IN_LENGTH
    LOOP
      CNT := CNT + 1;
      IN_CHAR := SUBSTR(IN_STRING, CNT, 1);
      DEC_CHAR := ASCII(IN_CHAR);
      -- blank out non alphanumerics
      IF ((DEC_CHAR >= 48 AND DEC_CHAR <= 57) OR
         (DEC_CHAR >= 65 AND DEC_CHAR <= 90)) 
      THEN
      --keep it
      OUT_CHAR := IN_CHAR;
      ELSE
        IF (DEC_CHAR >= 97 AND DEC_CHAR <= 122)
        THEN
          OUT_CHAR := CHR(DEC_CHAR - 32);
        ELSE
         OUT_CHAR := ' ';
        END IF;
      END IF;

      IF (NOT(PREV_SPACE AND OUT_CHAR = ' ')) 
      THEN
       OUT_STRING := OUT_STRING || OUT_CHAR;
      END IF;

      <<endloop>>
      IF (OUT_CHAR = ' ') THEN
       PREV_SPACE := TRUE;
      ELSE
       PREV_SPACE := FALSE;
      END IF;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN TRIM(OUT_STRING);
  END CLEAN_STRING;
```

I then created a simple test rig like tbone did, but I tested the three different routines against each other. First I verify that they all return the same results and then time each routine. Here is the test rig;

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  CURSOR PATHMAST_CURS
  IS
    SELECT PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS FROM PATHMAST WHERE ROWNUM < 100000;
  DUMMY CLOB;
  DUMMY_1 CLOB;
  DUMMY_2 CLOB;
  l_interval interval day to second(4);
  l_start timestamp;
  l_end timestamp;
  diff_count_1 binary_integer := 0;
  diff_count_2 binary_integer := 0;
BEGIN

  FOR PATH_REC IN PATHMAST_CURS
  LOOP
    DUMMY := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(NVL(PATH_REC.PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS,' '), '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
    DUMMY_1 := pathmast_utility_3.CLEAN_STRING(NVL(PATH_REC.PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS,' '));
    DUMMY_2 := regexp_replace(trim(translate(NVL(PATH_REC.PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS,' '),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()''_+-={[}]|/\":;,.<>?µ’±€'||chr(9),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ                                     ')),'( )* ',' ');
    IF DUMMY_1 != DUMMY
    THEN
      diff_count_1 := diff_count_1 + 1;
    END IF;
    IF DUMMY_2 != DUMMY
    THEN
      diff_count_2 := diff_count_2 + 1;
      dbms_output.put_line('Regexp: ' || DUMMY);
      dbms_output.put_line('Translate: ' || DUMMY_2);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('CLEAN_STRING differences: ' || diff_count_1);
  dbms_output.put_line('Translate differences: ' || diff_count_2);


  l_start := systimestamp;
  FOR PATH_REC IN PATHMAST_CURS
  LOOP
    DUMMY := UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(PATH_REC.PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]', ' '),'( )* ',' ')));
  END LOOP;
  l_end := systimestamp;
  l_interval := l_end - l_start;
  dbms_output.put_line('Regexp approach timing: ' || l_interval);
  -------------------------------------------------    
  l_start := systimestamp;
  FOR PATH_REC IN PATHMAST_CURS
  LOOP
    DUMMY := pathmast_utility_3.CLEAN_STRING(PATH_REC.PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS);
  END LOOP;
  l_end := systimestamp;
  l_interval := l_end - l_start;
  dbms_output.put_line('CLEAN_STRING approach timing: ' || l_interval);
  -------------------------------------------------  
  l_start := systimestamp;
  FOR PATH_REC IN PATHMAST_CURS
  LOOP
    DUMMY := regexp_replace(trim(translate(NVL(PATH_REC.PATHMAST_TEXT_DIAGNOSIS,' '),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()''_+-={[}]|/\":;,.<>?µ’±€'||chr(9),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ                                     ')),'( )* ',' ');
  END LOOP;
  l_end := systimestamp;
  l_interval := l_end - l_start;
  dbms_output.put_line('TRANSLATE approach timing: ' || l_interval);
  -------------------------------------------------  
END;
```

And here are the results;

```
anonymous block completed
CLEAN_STRING differences: 0
Translate differences: 0
Regexp approach timing: +00 00:00:52.9160
CLEAN_STRING approach timing: +00 00:00:05.5220
TRANSLATE approach timing: +00 00:00:13.4320
```

This is all without compiling native. So tbone is the big winner. Thank you tbone.

If for whatever reason you want/need to use the translate version, you should build the translate string programmatically in order to get all of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use TRANSLATE instead of regex to remove special characters and convert lower case to upper case.

```
regexp_replace(
               trim(
                    translate(x,
                              'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={[}]|/\"'':;,.<>?',
                              'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ                                '
                             )
                   ),
                   ' {2,}',
                   ' '
              )
```

Tried it on a table with 1000 rows and column with random characters from anywhere between 1 to 4000. 
Resulted in around 35% less time.(Did not try in PLSQL).